# curl long execution time on one server

Tags: php, curl

my curl execution time is very long, i run the **same** code on another server and there are very different results: these are the differences:

**server with long curl execution time**

```
{
   "url": "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=45.644843,8.9986268&sensor=false",
   "content_type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
   "http_code": 200,
   "header_size": 377,
   "request_size": 119,
   "filetime": -1,
   "ssl_verify_result": 0,
   "redirect_count": 0,
   "total_time": 127.26954,
   "namelookup_time": 0.001964,
   "connect_time": 127.23926,
   "pretransfer_time": 127.239265,
   "size_upload": 0,
   "size_download": 11729,
   "speed_download": 92,
   "speed_upload": 0,
   "download_content_length": -1,
   "upload_content_length": 0,
   "starttransfer_time": 127.269424,
   "redirect_time": 0,
   "certinfo": []
   "request_header":"GET \/maps\/api\/geocode\/json?latlng=45.644843,8.9986268&sensor=false HTTP\/1.1\r\nHost: maps.googleapis.com\r\nAccept: *\/*\r\n\r\n"
}
```

**server with short curl execution time**

```
{
   "url": "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=45.644843,8.9986268&sensor=false",
   "content_type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
   "http_code": 200,
   "header_size": 377,
   "request_size": 119,
   "filetime": -1,
   "ssl_verify_result": 0,
   "redirect_count": 0,
   "total_time": 0.116182,
   "namelookup_time": 0.012194,
   "connect_time": 0.027452,
   "pretransfer_time": 0.027473,
   "size_upload": 0,
   "size_download": 11729,
   "speed_download": 100953,
   "speed_upload": 0,
   "download_content_length": -1,
   "upload_content_length": 0,
   "starttransfer_time": 0.114101,
   "redirect_time": 0,
   "redirect_url": "",
   "primary_ip": "172.217.**.**",
   "certinfo": [],
   "primary_port": 80,
   "local_ip": "192.168.**.**",
   "local_port": 51393
   "request_header":"GET \/maps\/api\/geocode\/json?latlng=45.644843,8.9986268&sensor=false HTTP\/1.1\r\nHost: maps.googleapis.com\r\nAccept: *\/*\r\n\r\n"
}
```

What could be the problem with my server? I notice that in the first case there aren't ip references!

This is the server-code:

```
<?php
$latitudine = 45.644842999999995;
$longitudine = 8.9986268;
$geoloca = $latitudine.",".$longitudine;
$request = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$geoloca.'&sensor=false'; 
$file_contents = url_get_contents($request);


function url_get_contents($Url) {
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
        die('CURL is not installed!');
    }
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    echo(json_encode($info));
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
?>
```

Comment: Check out your server config, it does not seems to come from your call (enabled module, php config, etc.), try to disable not needed php modules

Comment: thanks for the comment, what i have to look for in my server config exactly?

Comment: many things can cause this, I think first start to disable php5 mods not necessary, disable xdebug if used, try with/without ssl, increase apache log level then check them... can you give us a sample of you php.ini and your apache configration file (if using apache)?

Comment: You can also try to check your servers environement, cpu/ram free, services started, etc. It may have another process that causes this problem.